# PHP PayPal Sandbox: Facilitator balance not updated

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to include the [REST API SDK for PHP](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK) in my project. Therefore I've tried to execute the given example, e.g. "PayPal Payments - similar to Express Checkout in Classic APIs" using [CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.php](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/payments/CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.php) (and [ExecutePayment.php](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/payments/ExecutePayment.php)). This works fine, the amount is withdrawn from the buyers account and the transaction is listed in both accounts (buyer and facilitator).

**But** the amount is not send to the facilitators balance, although the transaction is displayed as "Completed". So what am I missing here? I thought the amount will be send directly to the facilitators balance!??

I've set "Allow payments sent to me in a currency I do not hold:" to "Yes, accept and convert them to Euros" on [this page](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_profile-pref).
So USD and EUR are not processed correctly (amount is not booked on facilitators balance).

Creating a new payment via the following lines (haven't change something from the SDK sample code above):

```
$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setIntent("sale")
    ->setPayer($payer)
    ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
    ->setTransactions(array($transaction));
 $payment->create($this->apiContext);
```

After that the success method contains something like that:

```
// success method; i'm using Symfony 3.3
$paymentId = $request->query->get('paymentId');
$payment = Payment::get($paymentId, $this->apiContext);
$execution = new PaymentExecution();
$execution->setPayerId($request->query->get('PayerID'));
$result = $payment->execute($execution, $this->apiContext);
```

Payment state is now "approved".

Comment: Maybe check your currency, if you have an account in $ and pay in EUR it needs to convert. Also, show your requests and responses.

Comment: I've edited my post - it does not work with USD and EUR. Which responses exactly do you want to see? The "state" property of the payment object is "approved".

Comment: I've tried to use the "paypal/merchant-sdk-php" library using [this example code](https://gist.github.com/ArminVieweg/ce808de89aafd51cacf6) but I get the exact same result! I really don't know what's wrong here...

Comment: It's again me: I'm not sure if I'm the only one having this issue, but there is a chance that PayPal Sandbox is not working properly for the last days, see also [PayPal down](http://downdetector.com/status/paypal). Since I cannot fix this issue, I'll wait some days and hope that this gets resolved.

Comment: Hi, have you resolved this issue? I am experiencing the same.

Comment: @Kim Carlo: Unfortunately not, but I've tested it only months ago